# Issue with Size constraint in Grails domain class?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm newbie to Grails, I've a scenario where I've to restrict the chile elements to 5.

so using size constraint.

```
static constraints = {
  favoriteEplCircuitIds size 1..5
} 
 And static hasMany = [favoriteEplCircuitIds: String]
```

Now in my test case I'm expecting 'size.toobig' when i use parent?.errors['child']

but I'm getting a whole Exception  which is too long…how to suppress that?

@Burt: as per your suggestion I used

```
 assert 'size.toobig' == obj.errors.getFieldError('favoriteEplCircuitIds')
```

... but still getting the below long error message.

```
 Error Message : Field error in object 'com.src.UserSecurity' on field 'favoriteEplCircuitIds': rejected value [[a, b, c, d, e, f]]; 
codes [com.src.UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.error.com.src.UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds,
com.src.UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.error.favoriteEplCircuitIds,com.src.UserSecurity.
favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.error.java.util.Set,com.src.UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.error,userSecurity.
favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.error.com.src.UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds,userSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.error.
favoriteEplCircuitIds,userSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.error.java.util.Set,userSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.error,
com.src.UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.toobig.com.src.UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds,com.src.
UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.toobig.favoriteEplCircuitIds,com.src.UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.toobig.
java.util.Set,com.src.UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.toobig,userSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.toobig.com.twc.
eeportal.UserSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds,userSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.toobig.favoriteEplCircuitIds,userSecurity.
favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.toobig.java.util.Set,userSecurity.favoriteEplCircuitIds.size.toobig,size.toobig.com.src.UserSecurity.
favoriteEplCircuitIds,size.toobig.favoriteEplCircuitIds,size.toobig.java.util.Set,size.toobig]; arguments **[favoriteEplCircuitIds,class 
com.src.UserSecurity,[a, b, c, d, e, f],0,5]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] 
does not fall within the valid size range from [{3}] to [{4}]]'.**
```

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is wrong. It should be

```
static constraints = {
   child size: 1..5
}
```

assuming you have

```
static hasMany = [child: SomeOtherDomainClass]
```

It would be more natural to pluralize the collection name though, e.g. "children". But that's cosmetic and has nothing to do with the problem you're seeing.

**Edit:**

You can access the error with

```
def error = parent.errors.getFieldError('children')
```

but the toString() for that isn't very readable. To get the error that you would see in a GSP, dependency-inject the "messageSource" bean, e.g.

```
def messageSource
```

and then you can get the error message with

```
String message = messageSource.getMessage(error, Locale.default)
```

and it should look like this:

```
Property [children] of class [class Parent] with value [[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6]] does not fall within the valid size range from [1] to [5]
```

Comment: :It was a typo..I've edited my question… how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Burt thanks for your response…i use but still getting the below long error message. updated my question with the long error message...

Comment: I didn't say anything about " assert error ==", I showed how to retrieve the field error and get a readable string from it with placeholders resolved